# Attach an array with $this->form

Tags: zend-framework

I have an array in a log.phtml, ie:

```
<?php
//application/logmessage/log.phtml//

require_once 'Zend/Log.php';
require_once 'Zend/Log/Writer/Stream.php';

class Logger {

/**
 * Array variable store full file back trace information.
 *
 * @access protected
 */
protected $backTrace = array();

/**
 * Array variable store full message information.
 *
 * @access protected
 */
protected $messageInfo = array();

/**
 * Constructor: loads the debug and error logs.
 *
 */
public function __construct( $type, $msg ) {

    $mock = new Zend_Log_Writer_Mock;
    $logger = new Zend_Log( $mock );
    $logger->$type( $msg );

    // Get full message information.
    array_push( $this->messageInfo, $mock->events[0] );

    // Get full information of file, from where the message come.
    array_push( $this->backTrace, debug_backtrace() );

    // Set all required informationn in their respective variables. 
    $messageText = $this->messageInfo[0]["message"];
    $priority = $this->messageInfo[0]["priorityName"];
    $backTraceFile = $this->backTrace[0][0]["file"];
    $backTraceLine = $this->backTrace[0][0]["line"];

    $logArray = array( "Message" => $messageText, "Priority" => $priority, 
                   "Line" => $backTraceLine, "File" => $backTraceFile );

    }
}
?>
```

Now i want to display the $logArray array along with form, my form file is like:

```
<?php 
//application/views/scripts/miscellaneous/index.phtml//

//require_once('../application/logmessage/log.phtml');

    echo $this->form;
?>
```

How could i display Log array with form ....?

How could i return $logArray() from " application/logmessage/log.phtml " to 
" application/views/scripts/miscellaneous/index.phtml "

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to acheive?

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your Logger:

```
public $logArray;
```

also change last line with

```
$this->logArray = array( "Message" => $messageText, "Priority" => $priority, 
               "Line" => $backTraceLine, "File" => $backTraceFile );

}
```

now you can access to $logArray from `view`, `controller`, `form`, etc. for example we call Logger in `controller` and send it to `view`

```
/** Controller **/
$logger = new Logger($msg, $type);
$this->view->logArray = $loagger->logArray;

/** View **/
print_r($this->logArray);
```

dont forget to replace `print_r` with your custom helper to create a beautiful user interface

```
echo $this->myCustomHelper($this->logArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

I visit http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.html and the only thing that I added is:

```
<?php

//application/logmessage/log.phtml//



require_once 'Zend/Log.php';
require_once 'Zend/Log/Writer/Stream.php';

class Logger {

    /**
     * Array variable store full file back trace information.
     *
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $backTrace = array();

    /**
     * Array variable store full message information.
     *
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $messageInfo = array();

    /**
     * Constructor: loads the debug and error logs.
     *
     */
    public function __construct( $type, $msg ) {

        $mock = new Zend_Log_Writer_Mock;
        $logger = new Zend_Log( $mock );
        $logger->$type( $msg );
        //var_dump($mock->events[0]);

        // Get full message information.
        array_push( $this->messageInfo, $mock->events[0] );

        // Get full information of file, from where the message come.
        array_push( $this->backTrace, debug_backtrace() );

        // Set all required informationn in their respective variables. 
        $messageText = $this->messageInfo[0]["message"];
        $priority = $this->messageInfo[0]["priorityName"];
        $backTracePath = $this->backTrace[0][0]["file"];
        $backTraceLine = $this->backTrace[0][0]["line"];

        $logArray = array( "Message" => $messageText, "Priority" => $priority, 
                   "Line" => $backTraceLine, "Path" => $backTracePath );

        // Pass the array for display.
        Zend_Registry::set('logArray', $logArray);
    }
}
?>
```

and a little code in

```
<?php
//application/views/scripts/miscellaneous/index.phtml//


    echo $this->form;

    $logArray = Zend_Registry::get('logArray');
    print_r($logArray);

?>
```

It works excellently.

Comment: i prefer to avoid using Zend_Registery, because it will turn off auto complete :D